# ¿ Por qué no se me guarda bien el número del numberpicker?

Tags: java, android, diálogo, numberpicker

Tengo 2 `numberPicker` en un `dialog`. El problema es que si selecciono "segundos" y despues "minutos" y le doy a ok, se me queda guardada *bien* los numeros. Pero si lo hago al revés, los segundos me cogen los de la anterior configuración, ¿ por qué?

Lo he puesto, al haber solo 1 boton , que se guarde en el 1º `numberpicker`, en `user_minutos.setText`

```
 //PRIMER NUMBERPICKER

 NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener myValChangedListener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
            user_minutos.setText(newVal + " min "+ minutos2 +"seg");
            minutos = newVal;


        }
    };

    aNumberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(myValChangedListener);

//SEGUNDO NUMBERPICKER

NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener myValChangedListener2 = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal2) {
            //user_minutos.setText(newVal + " seg");
            minutos2 = newVal2;

        }

    };

    aNumberPickerA.setOnValueChangedListener(myValChangedListener2);
```

Comment: A que te refieres con la anterior configuración?

Comment: Con lo que he seleccionado anteriormente

Comment: Selecciono 5 minutos y 4 segundos. Si despues selecciono 6 minutos y 7 segundos, me salen **6 minutos** (que está bien) y **4 segundos** que es lo que puse anteriormente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suponiendo que ''minutos2'' esta puesto como variable de clase, lo que pasa es que cuando le das al primer datapicker pues se actualiza el valor de ''newVal'' y te sale correcto tu info, cuando le das a los segundos se actualiza la info de segundos y cuando le das a tu data picker de minutos los segundos estan actualizados. y sale correcto de nuevo.

Cuando le das a los segundos por segunda vez pues actualizas el valor de segundos en la variable pero no en inputtext por lo que no cambia.

```
//variables 
int minutos=0;
int segundos=0;
//PRIMER NUMBERPICKER

NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener myValChangedListener = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
        minutos = newVal;
        user_minutos.setText(newVal + " min "+ segundos+"seg");



     }
   };

aNumberPicker.setOnValueChangedListener(myValChangedListener);

     //SEGUNDO NUMBERPICKER

     NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener myValChangedListener2 = new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal2) {
        minutos2 = newVal2;
       user_minutos.setText(newVal + " min "+ segundos+"seg");


    }

};

aNumberPickerA.setOnValueChangedListener(myValChangedListener2);
```

Comment: no, ``minutos2`` es como ``minutos``, es decir, como ``int``. Voy a probar lo que dices, ponerlo encima y no debajo.

Comment: Sí que funciona, era esa chorrada ya ves... además de duplicar el mensaje, +1 para ti.